# How to programmatically convert HTML to epub?

Tags: html, automation, epub

Can I do this conversion with any programming language or library?

Comment: Did you wind up settling on a process? Looking for a PHP solution myself.

Comment: After try different programs, I think this is much better: http://www.juliansmart.com/ecub Though it is not open source.

Comment: I think you are interested in this: https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub

Answer (score 62):

The short answer is yes, it can be done in any programming language.

Basic steps:

1. Convert your HTML to XHTML (+ CSS). This can be done in your program or through an XSLT file.
2. Copy your files (XHTML, CSS, any images and fonts) into a directory structure that follows the format.
3. Zip the directory structure up and name the archive with a ".epub" extension.

Some web sites to help you get started:

- A good tutorial for what's in an epub file (and how to create one yourself) can be found here: http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/Introduction.shtml. I used this to get started myself.
- Specs for the .epub standard are here: http://www.idpf.org/
- A validator for .epubs can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck

**June 2015 Note:** The epubcheck validator has moved from google code to GitHub; note the new URL.

Answer (score 16):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) supports a wide variety of input formats, including HTML, and a wide variety of output formats, including EPUB, but it's not "a programming language or library".  Are there specific reasons you desire a programming-based approach rather than a free-standing tool?  If so, maybe Python and [ebookmaker.py](https://web.archive.org/web/20120126113934/http://www.egofile.com/code/ebookmaker.py), for example, could help you.

Comment: I want to automatise a process.

Comment: calibre can be run from the command line

Comment: Agree..I've used it from the command line myself, integrated with some bash scripting. Good for small-ish books. My larger pubs created by Calibre never pass validation.

Comment: Unfortunately Calibre does not support ePub 3.0.

Comment: @arlomedia It does now

Answer (score 4):

A late reply, but I found the Python 3-based [ebookmaker](https://github.com/setanta/ebookmaker) to be of value, at least after I contributed a pull request to remove a UTF-8 BOM. One problem with it appears to be that it uses [brittle regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but I guess I'll have to report it there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [pdf to epub](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfpdf2epub.aspx), I know that's not what you're after, but it's a start.

The [calibre](https://launchpad.net/calibre) package may have what you want

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following library from Aspose - http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

In just two lines of code I am able to do html to epub conversions. Using this currently in a production system.

Document doc = new Document(_sourceFilePath);

doc.Save(_destinationFilePath, SaveFormat.Epub);

Answer (score 1):

I just started to implement such a tool in Java (OpenJDK compatible): [html2epub](https://github.com/skreutzer/automated_digital_publishing/tree/master/html2epub). In order to get rid of manually editing the config file, I'll probably start a separate tool to generate the config file from any given directory (however, it would still be necessary to determine the order of the XHTMLs in the EPUB - for non-programmatical use, developing a GUI helper tool could be considered, for a fully flexible programmatical solution, I haven't come up with an idea yet). Before that, I implemented shell script based converters for custom XML input ([hag2epub tools](http://www.freie-bibel.de/official/tools/hag2epub/)) - in case you're interested, I would probably port them to XHTML input (with a config file for the EPUB metadata or obtaining metadata from the topmost index.html of a directory, if existing).

Comment: if you would license it under Apache 2.0 it would be way to go for many people, as its under AGPL i cannot use it. its pitty :(

Comment: Could you please tell me how the AGPL could possibly blocking you from using it?

Comment: cannot use AGPL in commercial product

Comment: That's simply not true. To the contrary: being usable in a commercial context or as a commercial product is an important right free software grants its users, so does the AGPL too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue previously, necause I want to read some webpage content offline on my iPad. I have no idea and I am not a computer savvy. There are calibre or stanza blabla....

But for me they are just formats converters and I need a ePub book creator which will allows me to combine many desired documents together to read. Then I found a bookish [html to ePub converter](http://www.epubcreator.net/html-to-epub-converter.html), I save the html page from web then convert with it. It's a quite good tool for me now.